# Excel Auto Generates Formula Based on Another Column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with an Excel spreadsheet and noticed something interesting.

When there's nothing in cell A1, there's no formula or value in cell B1.
When I enter a value in cell A1, cell B1 generates a formula by itself.
The same thing applies to entire columns A and B.

Does anyone know what function in Excel can make this happen?

Comment: Look into `worksheet_change`.

Comment: <kdb>Alt+F11</kdb> to the rescue (open the VBA programming environment)

Comment: Double click the worksheet on the vba navigator and you will see the [worksheet_change](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/worksheet-change-event/). These are called events, they are on every application, like when you open the workbook, or you can create your own with class modules. This is a topic on its own that I would suggest you to learn about.